# Convert dd, mm, yy arrays to numpy datetime

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to convert separate arrays of YY, MM, DD values to a `numpy datetime64` array.  Here is the code

```
import numpy as np

iyy = [2020, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017]
imm = [2, 4, 4, 6, 8]
idd = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

isod = []
for y, m, d in zip(iyy, imm, idd):
    isod.append("%4d-%02d-%02d" % (y, m, d))

t1 = np.datetime64(np.asarray(isod))
```

This gives the error `Could not convert object to NumPy datetime`.  Would appreciate any suggestions for achieving this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
np.datetime64(np.asarray(isod))
```

to

```
np.asarray(isod).astype(np.datetime64)
```

Full code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1LCsMwDET3PsVQCNjghvz6hZ6kZGFwSr2wIxx34V4@VdxWiAcaaUaU03MO/bo6T3NMCC9PGWZBICFczrjh3jVdo/Fneyk8F55G4bwvRxpD6aPGmVVrN7XlK42@LA4jJy5z0UfxmCOyhtewcAFvR5LfaXAcw1p1FeDaDLUhmoKVu2qw@6rpvtihgvwlKCVEajk4UG0WE6PJcnMqnlKmSbJuTZqS89NxUIKiC0mmVq3rBw)

```
import numpy as np

iyy = [2020, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017]
imm = [2, 4, 4, 6, 8]
idd = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

isod = []
for y, m, d in zip(iyy, imm, idd):
    isod.append("%4d-%02d-%02d" % (y, m, d))

t1 = np.asarray(isod).astype(np.datetime64)
print(t1)
```

Output:

```
['2020-02-01' '2020-04-02' '2019-04-03' '2018-06-04' '2017-08-05']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the conversion to `numpy.datetime64` in a list comprehension, then create a `numpy.array` from that list

```
>>> np.array([np.datetime64('{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(y, m, d)) for y, m, d in zip(iyy, imm, idd)])
array(['2020-02-01', '2020-04-02', '2019-04-03', '2018-06-04', '2017-08-05'],
      dtype='datetime64[D]')
```